# Receiving Duplicate FCM Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I have implemented the code to receive FCM notifications, I have set up the code and everything is working well but the issue is that the notifications are duplicated and I checked the post request and it is not causing any duplicate but `onMessageReceived` is called twice and I couldn't figure the reason why, I have checked some other topics regarding my issue and I got to check whether I'm having anything that triggers GCM along with FCM but everything is okey.

```
 public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private int num;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
   
    private String serverUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    private String authKey = "key=AIzaSyAwrrIexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

     ///i'm sending data to server in oncreate method
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PostDataQll();
    }

     ///this is where i received message back from server
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Map<String, String> map = remoteMessage.getData();
        String title = map.get("title");
        String body = map.get("body");

        if (!Objects.requireNonNull(body).equals("")) {
            shownotification(body, title);
        }

    }

    //////show notification 
    void shownotification(String mytime, String awayteam) {

        num = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), 
                 notificationhelper.channelid)
                .setContentText("Now : " + awayteam)
                .setContentTitle(mytime)
                .setChannelId(notificationhelper.channelid)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .build();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            SystemClock.sleep(3000);
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(num, notification);
        }


    }
    /////posting data to the fcm server
    void post(String url, String json) {
        Log.d("TODO", "posted data" + " " + "Yes posted");
        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", authKey)
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            }
        });

    }
     ////in this method , the user subscribes to the topic 
     //// this is just quickie sample of the data i'm sending to server 
     private void PostDataQll() {


        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("spanishsport");

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("to", "/topics/spanishsport");
            notification.put("title", "France" + " vs " + "Italy");
            notification.put("body", "20'");
            jsonObject.put("data", notification);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", jsonObject.toString());


    }
```

- This is registering the service in manifest file

```
       <service
            android:name=".notificationui.NotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `PostDataQll()` in `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Well PostDatzQll() is a function which posts the data to the fcm server in oncreate , where else should i put the posting function !! and i noticed that fcm duplication issue has been asked about by many people , and i also checked to see wether any thing related to GCM , i found nothing ..so i'm really clueless why that is happening , i checked also my permissions , there are no permission related to GCM

Comment: Your PostDataQll is not even dynamic you can literally call it anywhere when you put it on seperate class  together with function post. PostDataQll post json on https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send that trigger the firebaseMessagingService that call onCreate method and call the function PostDataQll. You are creating a infinite loop, try understanding the flow of your code.

Comment: Try asking yourself why do I put the `PostDataQll()` in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Well i have no other methods in which i call that function, i have onMessageReceived , so i don't really know which method to override and call that function ,like when we have a class that extends the normal sevice , in oncreate we initiate some variables for example and oncreate is called when the service is created , but on startcommand , the service is being called , i dont have on startcommand in myclass which extends FirebaseMessagingService, i checked also topics where they post json object to fcm server but they only show piece of code so i couldn't take a hint of where they call it ,

Comment: what is your objective in posting your notification? When the user open the app it will send notification?

Comment: Well everything is working when it comes to sending notifications , my app is about sports , so when there is live games , i notify the users that a certain game is playing now , even when i restart the app i still get the notificatio, but either on foreground or background , the notification is duplicated

Comment: how do you trigger when there is a live games?

Comment: i get data from api , like home team and away team , time and date , and then i post them to fcm server , receive the data back onMessageReceived method , then i pass the data to my notification code

Comment: how do you call your api? via web socket(realtime) or using POST or GET method?

Comment: Using POST method

Comment: Ok I'm not gonna go any deeper in your objectives, the notification duplication is because of your PostDataQll() in onCreate() method it create a infinite loop but you only receive 2 notification because FCM prevent flooding redundant post to prevent overloading there API.

Comment: I recommend you directly send notification in you webserver rather sending it on android then the android make a notification post on FCM api. You just add 1 unnecessary operation.

Comment: well i dont have a webserver for now that's my problem and i dont know how to create one , i dont have experience with that

Comment: Mate i figured it out thank you , and the issue was from the oncreate i guess , so what i did is move the post function to my fragment and called it on the oncreate and now there is no duplicate notifications , thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called as mate @L2_Paver said, I had to post the json object from my fragment.